# How to get JQuery to accept a JSON reply?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Here's some simple Javascript:

```
(function($){
    var ajax_callback = function(data) { window.location.hash = data.h1; };
    $('.clickable').live('click', function() { 
             $.post('server.fcgi', {}, ajax_callback, 'json');
         }
    );
})(jQuery);
```

The server is a c++ binary (yes, i know) that spits out (through fast_cgi) the string:
`{"h1":"newhash"}`.

The expected behavior is that the URL should change. 
Instead, nothing happens and Firebug complains that 'data' is "null"!. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Will.

When the following code enters "ajax_callback", it says that "data" is "null"!. 
But the server is a c++ binary that is confirmed to return the JSON string `{"h1":"newhash"}`. 
Anyone have an idea why JQuery seems unable to accept the JSON data when calling the ajax_callback?

Comment: Is the content type of your response from the server "application/json"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the server also returns the correct HTTP headers before the payload. E.g.:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: ...
...

{"h1":"bla"}
```

From your description, I could not quite make out if all it did was `printf("{\"h1\":\"bla\"}");` or not.

To check the actual result, use a command line tool like `HEAD`, `GET`, `wget`, `curl`, or even `nc`. If you are not able to use one of those, you might get some clues from the Net panel in Firebug and the like.

Comment: I'd recommend Fiddler if you're on a windows machine. It's a solid HTTP request/response viewer.

Comment: Thank you. Embarrassingly.. i had forgotten then "\r\n\r\n" after the header, and this error meant nothing was getting through at all. 
(Perhaps not a good design decision to make it fail silently). 

Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

I did have similar problem as you have mentioned when using $.POST().
There are two things if you are using jquery $.post method. You need to add an extra bracket before defined data type ("JSON") as shown below. I don't know why but it works, it will return data.

```
$.post('server.fcgi', {}, ajax_callback,{}, 'json');
```

The second thing is that you will need to parse JSON data using $.parseJSON(data) in side the callback function.

One more thing to make sure that the url to fetch JSON, the page document type should be defined as JSON in the header.

I have given an example below.

```
$.post("url/path/here/to/json", {}, function(data){

    if(data){ // just in case the called program had a problem
         var obj =  $.parseJSON(data);
        .... do everything else using the Obj->         
    }
},{},"json");
```

This will work.

However I recommend to you to use another Jquery function specially implemented for JSON, that is called

```
$.getJSON();
```

Here is the [url for more information](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

And I am suggesting you to use the following method instead of the one described by you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.clickable').live('click', function() { 
             $.getJSON('server.fcgi', function(data){
                         window.location.hash = data.h1;
              });
         }
    );
});
```

Comment: What this solution is doing as far as I can tell is simply making the dataType argument an empty object. I believe .post defaults to a dataType of "text", so that's why this works.

Comment: I do agree with @ Ryan Kinal comment, may be that is the reason it is working that way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
I think i will use getJSON as you suggest. 

Here's a silly thing i found out (the hard way): you need a "\r\n\r\n" after the JSON headers. 

I guess if you use php or perl those are automatically generated in the header, but for c/c++ users you actually have to output those "by hand". 
That solved just one part of the problem, your reply solved the rest. 

Thank you!

Comment: You are most welcome. I am glad to be able to provide you the right answer. It's great to know that it is now working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you want to hear, but I assume you're using jQuery 1.4.2? I noticed that this does work as expected in 1.3.2 so you might want to consider using that instead. :(